# White screen after Splashscree phonegap2.9.0

Tags: ios, cordova, sencha-touch-2

In my phonegap based application.I have implement a project via ios.When i try to show the splashscreen. Its showing and a white screen diplays for a seconds and after that only application loading.What is the problem .please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem:

The steps to solve the problem are (works for me):

1. Add this line in config.xml of your project
2. Copy your splash screen files in: Resources/splash
   This files should be included in this path
3. And your index.html : to show splash screen

   ```
   function onDeviceReady() {
           navigator.splashscreen.show();
       }
   ```

   1. to hide splash screen
          navigator.splashscreen.hide();

But... I set this line in my config.xml to auto hide the splash screen

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
```

You can use the following steps for the splash screen

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen